# Helm 2 an Helm 3 in the same cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Is it possible to install new packages with helm3 while helm2 is running in the cluster with tiller?

Any potential problems to packages installed with helm2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a problem. Helm v2 talks to tiller, Helm v3 doesn't. Just basically keep:

- Every package managed with Helm v2 using Helm v2
- Every package managed with Helm v3 managed with Helm v3

Eventually, you will have to [migrate everything to Helm v3](https://helm.sh/blog/migrate-from-helm-v2-to-helm-v3/). One thing is that if you install the latest Helm v3 the client executable will have the `helm` name. So you'd like to maybe rename the v2 client executable to helm2 and the v3 client executable to v3 to keep yourself from becoming confusing.